# Android - libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, permission-denied

I am trying to write an image to a file according to the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). However, I get this exception:
    `libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`
Here is my code where this exception apparently pops up:

```
private File createImageFile(int side) throws IOException {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "";
        if (side==1) {
            imageFileName = "Front_"+timestamp;
        } else {
            imageFileName = "Side_"+timestamp;
        }
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );

        // Save the file
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:"+image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that instead of 
`File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);` it should be 
`File storageDir = this.getExternalFilesDir(null);`